# Android turn off phone, but NOT wifi

Tags: android

Since I use the phone as a XBMC remote control, all I need is the Wifi connection, and thus I'd like to turn off the "phone" function for better battery time, or really any phone function that is not Wifi. Any way to do this with the SDK ? (i.e. I'm not asking for the airplane mode)

Comment: Detail which phone functions you want to turn off.

Comment: Well.. *the* phone function.. 3G/4G ?, i.e. I won't need to be able to answer any calls with the phone.. :) I updated the question with more detail.